# Send parameter from html to method in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I have table and I show contents of this table in html. Every record that is showed has button. I want to send id of the record on button click to the method of my controller. What am I doing wrong?

my_controller.rb

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  skip_authorization_check

def index
  @contacts = Mytable.all
end

def add
  byebug
  ap params[:id]
end
end
```

index.html.slim

```
- debug(params) if Rails.env.development?
body
center
  p
    |
      Contacts.
  p.contact-list
     - @contacts.each do |a|
          .name
              p.fname
                = a['fname']
          .surname
              p.lname
                = a['lname']
      .phone
          p.phone
            = a['phone']

          .rocknroll
                    p.rock
               = link_to 'Add', method: add, class: 'icon', value: a['id ']
```

routes.rb

```
get 'my/' => 'my#index', as: 'my'
get 'my/add'
```

error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `add'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `add'

I believe the error is from this line

```
= link_to 'Add', method: add, class: 'icon', value: a['id ']
```

There isn't a method `add`. The available methods are `get`, `post`, `put` etc

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to modify an existing record, you should use a PATCH method. Take a look at the examples [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

I think it should be something along the lines of:

```
= link_to 'Add', method: :patch, class: 'icon', value: a['id ']
```

And in routes.rb

```
resources :contacts do #Assuming you have a Contact model
  member do
    patch 'add' #Or whatever you want to call your method.
  end
end
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.